# Why do Richfaces notifyStack show duplicates?

Tags: jsf-2, richfaces, jboss7.x

When a user logs in or out I add a faces context message. e.g.

```
facesContext.addMessage(null, new FacesMessage("Loged out"));
```

However, the messages appears twice. No matter wheather for logout or login.

```
    <rich:notifyStack id="loginInfoStack" position="bottomRight"
        direction="vertical" method="first">
        <rich:notifyMessages stayTime="5000" nonblocking="false"
            showCloseButton="false" showShadow="false" />
    </rich:notifyStack>
```

For a few seconds I thought I would invoke the login twice, but that is not the case. (I debugged.)

I'm using RF 4.3.3.

Any hints?

Comment: Can you provide more code? Checking just this I see no duplicates.

Comment: Sorry Makhiel. You would have immediately guessed it. The reason was, that I was rendering @all after clicking the login/logout button (means, all widgets), instead of only a selective set of IDs. This triggered also the message notification a second time. I used <a4j:region> to better focus on the set of panels which need to rerender.